# Data explorer data have not been updated for some sites

Tags: bug, data-explorer

Data explorer page says "Data updated May 8 at 3:27", but for some sites such as Mathematics, Math Overflow, Physics, etc... the newest added post is from May 1. For example this query show most recent post date on Physics stack exchange https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1590035/time-of-the-most-recent-post and it currently gives "2022-05-01 04:19:49".

Out of the few sites I've tried Stack Overflow was the only one that seemed to be updated.